# Swiffy and dfp generate too much impressions

Tags: html, flash, google-dfp, google-swiffy

I am having some issues with ads that were converted with swiffy google developer tool.

I test with two swf files converted to HTML5 and the banner works great, but in DFP (DoubleClick for Publishers) ad server reports, I have thousands of impressions of this two html5 ads.
Those impressions are wrong, for example in a page that has 10.000 impressions I can see 190.000 impressions of one HTML5 converted banner.
The other problem is that dfp is not counting clicks on those banners and I have added this line:

```
stage.setFlashVars("clickTag=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%");
```

In the correct part of the code. ( I use [THIS LINK](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/6263288?hl=en) )

So, does anybody has any experience converting swf files to HTML5 and use them in DFP ad server?

Comment: Just making sure that you are trafficking this creative / asking this question based on the assumption that we're using the Third Party Creative type?

Comment: @akmozo, Yes I am using third party creative. Perhaps the problem is that the click tag is case sensitive. I am asking for the .fla to watch that. thanks

Comment: @Nicopag The question was from kevinMario not from me ;)